# Como criar uma busca de unidades mais proximas com google api

Tags: php, google-maps

Preciso montar uma busca que a pessoa seleciona o estado e no mapa aparecem as unidades mais proximas, como na imagem, como faço? não sei por onde começar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você precisa que seja em PHP ou pode ser com JavaScript?

Comment: pode ser qualquer um

Comment: Fiz algo parecido esses dias. No caso eu fiz pegando a localização atual do cliente, depois fiz o filtro com base num raio determinado, algo como:

$limit = '1,86411'; // 2,999994244 km
    
$query = '( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$lat.') ) *
                            cos( radians( enderecos.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( enderecos.longitude ) - radians('.$long.') ) +
                            sin( radians('.$lat.') ) *
                            sin( radians( enderecos.latitude ) ) ) )'
), '<=', $limit);

A partir daí você pode usar a imaginação e pensar em como montar a consulta

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar a [Biblioteca do Google Places](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=pt-br):

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500', //Ditância máxima em todas direlções a partir da Longitude e Latitude informados
    types: ['store'] //Que tipos de lugares deve mostrar
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Ela é bem completa e você pode fazer vários filtros como distância máxima, organizar os itens por proximidade, entre outros recomendo que leia a documentação